# How to enable Javascript - webbrowser for windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am creating a windows 7.1 phone app where I am using webbrowser to display some web content. 
I want to know how to enable JavaScript in the browser object in my app?
I have set the IsScriptEnabled property to true but that does not seem to help.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the MSDN [WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) help you have to refresh WebBrowser content after enabling scripts to make it really happen:

> **WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled Property**
>   Enables or disables scripting.
>   *This applies to the next document that is navigated to, not the
>   current document*. This property is false by default. Set this property
>   to true to enable scripting, or false to disable scripting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that the property applies to the next page. 

I found that only thing that works in the app is javascript:history.back() function that indicates that js is loaded in the browser but I can not make any js alerts on the webpage to appear on windows phone browser.

Comment: all the alerts work fine when the same page is viewed in the browser of the phone simulator. Its only in the app, when displaying the page in a webbrowser control - the js alerts will not work, inspite of IsScriptEnabled property is set to true and I am testing on the subsiquent pages (not on the 1st page)

Answer (score 1):

It's more than enabling the scripts in the webbrowser, you also need to add a ScriptNotify handler.

```
 <phone:WebBrowser Name="browser"
                          IsScriptEnabled="True"
                          ScriptNotify="browser_ScriptNotify"
                          Source="HTML/Default.html"/>
```