# enable javascript wp7

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, windows-phone-7

I am in desperate need of help. I am developing an application on windows phone in C# and it includes a web browser on one of the pages linked to a youtube video. The only problem is, is on the emulator it says javascript needs to be enabled. How do I do this.

I am aware of this code:  public bool IsScriptEnabled { get; set; }

but I have no idea where to put this and what do with it. And would I put something like this in a method: webbrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = ture; ??

Lets Say that the method button2_Click leads me to a new page where the Web Browser is present. Do I enable java script in the button method? Or Do I Enable it on the page where the actual browser is present.

Here is a picture to go along with the last paragraph

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ispWD.jpg

Comment: Pretty sure YoutTube videos will not play in a WP7 WebView or has this changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="NameOfBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

Also remember if you enable it using code (NameOfBrowser.IsScriptEnabled= True), then you will need to refresh the page to see the effect.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9395586/546896